# Get system logged in user and display on web page using react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I have internal web application front end is reactjs and backend is nodejs, which is deployed on production server and works in intranet environment. I need to get the client username who access the url in his machine. I mean if logged to winodws machine and accessing web app url in browser, i need to display windows logged user in web page. I tried this `'<%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>'` but no luck. Any help much appreciated

Comment: One way to achieve this is using LDAP. You have to setup authentication using LDAP for your organisation. Not sure are you asking this only or something else. This is one way. There might be other ways too.

Comment: i will have to setup user details in LDAP, but I don't want any authentication. I just want to get user who is accessing this url in company